# Framework7 + Object Oriented Single-Page Script

Tags: javascript, php, html, single-page-application, html-framework-7

I use this object-oriented PHP script: http://phpsound.com/demo
Every page is loaded in a wrapper (wrapper.html) which contains the header and footer. The page layouts / templates are stored as explore/content.html , profile/content.html , etc.

I tried using this in my wrapper.html:

```
<div class="views">
  <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class-->
  <div class="view view-main">
    <!-- Top Navbar-->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <!-- We have home navbar without left link-->
        <div class="center sliding">{$title}</div>
        <div class="right">
          <!-- Right link contains only icon - additional "icon-only" class--><a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"> <i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Pages, because we need fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
    <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
      <!-- Page, data-page contains page name-->

      {$content}

    </div>
    <!-- Bottom Toolbar-->
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="toolbar-inner"><a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a><a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The $content is automatically loaded through its respective html template file. The profile pages use the profile/content.html layout and the track pages use the track/content.html layout. So, I made each of these content pages appear as this:

```
  <div data-page="explore(or whatever page template each is)" class="page">
     <div class="page-content">
       <div class="content-block-title">Welcome To My Awesome App</div>
          <div class="content-block">       
             <div class="row-body{$content_class}">
                {template content goes here}
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The initial page then loads fine, but upon clicking any links, the page does not load the link and the title of the page just changed to "undefined". I tried disabling the ajax loading of pages but that didn't work either.
So, how do I get a single page web app loading its pages through html template files that display dynamic user content via a PHP classes file to work with Framework7?